# Navigating to IndexRoute causes all future route transitions to no longer render correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Navigating around my app routes works fine however there is an edge case - if I navigate to Link X, then IndexRoute, then Link Y my components return the content of Link X but the props all point to Link Y. All further attempts to navigate the routes continue to serve Link X.

I'm unsure if this is an issue with my configuration of Reflux or React-Router. For what it is worth I'm using React 0.14.15 & React-Router 1.0.0

**Routes**

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <IntlProvider>
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} > 
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path=":slug" component={Page} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </IntlProvider>
), document.getElementById('grandeur'));
```

**Page Component - responsible or handling the routes**

```
var Page = React.createClass({
mixins: [
        Router.History
    ],
getInitialState() {
    return {
        loading: !PageStore.loaded,
        page: PageStore.getInitialState()
    }
},
onPageChange: function(response) {
    this.setState({
        loading: false,
        page: response
    });
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log('did mount')
    console.log(this.props)
    this.unsubscribe = PageStore.listen(this.onPageChange);
    if (!PageStore.loaded) PageActions.Load(this.props.params.slug);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    console.log('unmounting')
    this.unsubscribe();
},
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    console.log('received props')
    console.log(nextProps)
    console.log(this.props)
    PageActions.Load(nextProps.params.slug);
},
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('should update')
    console.log(nextProps !== this.props)
    if (nextState !== this.state || nextProps !== this.props) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
pageContent: function() {
    if(!_.isEmpty(this.state.page) || this.state.loading == false){
        if(this.state.page.content.rendered.includes('[blog]')){
            return <Posts/>;
        }else{
            return <SinglePage page={this.state.page}/>;
        }
    }
},
render: function () {
    var content = this.pageContent();
    return (
        <div className="content">
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

Any input or criticism is much appreciated.